# SQL query causing A TOP N value may not be negative error

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am creating a asp.net game rental website using SQL Server 2008 and have a delivery page which when I run this code causes a `TOP N` value error.

I have found one query on my page which runs when pages loads from an sqldatasource but it doesnt contain any top minus figures.

```
    SELECT TOP (
    SELECT MIN([Rentability].[RemainingRentable])
    FROM (
      /* Remaining rentable at a time */
      SELECT
        [Subscriptions].[Game_at_a_time] - (
          /* Number of games currently rented by the customer */
          SELECT COUNT(*) AS [CurraentlyRented]
          FROM [Rentals]
          WHERE [Rentals].[Date_returned] IS NULL
            AND [Users].[User_ID] = [Rentals].[User_ID]
        ) AS RemainingRentable
      FROM [Users]
      JOIN [Subscriptions]
        ON [Users].[Subscription_ID] = [Subscriptions].[Subscription_ID]
      WHERE [Users].[User_ID] = 1 /* CHANGE THIS to your Customer ID */
      UNION
      SELECT
        [Subscriptions].[Max_games] - (
          /* Number of total games rented by the customer this month */
          SELECT COUNT(*) AS [RentedThisMonth]
          FROM [Rentals]
          WHERE MONTH([Rentals].[Date_rented]) = MONTH(GETDATE())
            AND YEAR([Rentals].[Date_rented]) = MONTH(GETDATE())
            AND [Users].[User_ID] = [Rentals].[User_ID]
        ) AS RemainingRentable
      FROM [Users]
      JOIN [Subscriptions]
        ON [Users].[Subscription_ID] = [Subscriptions].[Subscription_ID]
      WHERE [Users].[User_ID] = 1 /* CHANGE THIS to your Customer ID */
    ) Rentability) [Games].[Game_barcode]FROM [Games]JOIN [Favourites]ON [Favourites].[Game_name] = [Games].[Name] JOIN [Users] ON [Users].[User_ID] = [Favourites].[User_ID] WHERE [Users].[User_ID] = 1 /* CHANGE THIS to your Customer ID */
  AND [Games].[Quantity] > (
    /* Number of currently rented copies */
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Rentals]
    WHERE [Games].[Game_barcode] = [Rentals].[Game_barcode]
      AND [Rentals].[Date_returned] IS NULL
  )
ORDER BY Favourites.Priority, Favourites.DatePicked asc;
```

Comment: Do you need to investigate why there is a negative `[Rentability].[RemainingRentable]`? Also, FWIW, spelling: CurraentlyRented->CurrentlyRented.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a CASE statement to ensure that you never get a negative number:

```
SELECT TOP (
    SELECT CASE WHEN MIN([Rentability].[RemainingRentable]) < 0 THEN 0 
        ELSE MIN([Rentability].[RemainingRentable]) END AS RemainingRentable
    FROM (
        /* Remaining rentable at a time */
          SELECT
            [Subscriptions].[Game_at_a_time] - (
              /* Number of games currently rented by the customer */
              SELECT COUNT(*) AS [CurraentlyRented]
              FROM [Rentals]
              WHERE [Rentals].[Date_returned] IS NULL
                AND [Users].[User_ID] = [Rentals].[User_ID]
            ) AS RemainingRentable
              FROM [Users]
              JOIN [Subscriptions]
                ON [Users].[Subscription_ID] = [Subscriptions].[Subscription_ID]
              WHERE [Users].[User_ID] = 1 /* CHANGE THIS to your Customer ID */
          UNION
          SELECT
            [Subscriptions].[Max_games] - (
              /* Number of total games rented by the customer this month */
              SELECT COUNT(*) AS [RentedThisMonth]
              FROM [Rentals]
              WHERE MONTH([Rentals].[Date_rented]) = MONTH(GETDATE())
                AND YEAR([Rentals].[Date_rented]) = MONTH(GETDATE())
                AND [Users].[User_ID] = [Rentals].[User_ID]
            ) AS RemainingRentable
          FROM [Users]
          JOIN [Subscriptions]
            ON [Users].[Subscription_ID] = [Subscriptions].[Subscription_ID]
          WHERE [Users].[User_ID] = 1 /* CHANGE THIS to your Customer ID */
        ) Rentability
    ) [Games].[Game_barcode]
    FROM [Games]
    JOIN [Favourites] ON [Favourites].[Game_name] = [Games].[Name] 
    JOIN [Users] ON [Users].[User_ID] = [Favourites].[User_ID] 
    WHERE [Users].[User_ID] = 1 /* CHANGE THIS to your Customer ID */
      AND [Games].[Quantity] > (
        /* Number of currently rented copies */
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Rentals]
        WHERE [Games].[Game_barcode] = [Rentals].[Game_barcode]
          AND [Rentals].[Date_returned] IS NULL
  )
ORDER BY Favourites.Priority, Favourites.DatePicked asc;
```